# Finding Bevel Angle

Tags: matlab, geometry

I need to find the bevel angle (half the angle of the inward normals) of a "box" with 4, 5, 6 or 8 sides.  The shape is tilting outward at 10 and 20 degrees. All sides are the same length, and the bevel angle should be the same for each. How would I go about computing this?

Assuming the tilt angle looks something like this:
http://jansson.us/planterboxes.jpg
Would the tilt angle effect the bevel angle of the box?

My first idea is that since it is box with an overall shape with a standard side length, I could simply solve with a simple equation like this:

360 degrees/number of sides

I then need to use Matlab to create a function that will calculate the bevel angle with the given input variables.

Would this method of solving work, or would the tilt angle require a more involved way of solving?

Diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNCzd.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by bevel angle (I just doubt in English term meaning). Angle between inclined edge and vertical? (0 for cube)

Comment: The "Bevel" angle is half the angle formed by the inward normals.

Comment: Normals of what ? Edges? Faces?

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to explain it. Here is a diagram: https://imgur.com/a/Zvp6iwY

Comment: It's the angle relative to the perpendicular line of the side.  The bevel angle is just the angle the sides need to be "cut" at for each side to be the same length.  So for a square the bevel angle would be 45 degrees.

Comment: Inner angle of regular n-gon is 180*(n-2)/n  : 90 for square, 120 for hexagon. Do you look for half of this value?

Comment: Using that equation would it still work with the outward tilt?

Comment: Yes, square remains square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner angle of regular n-gon is `180*(n-2)/n` ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Angles)) : 90 for square, 120 for hexagon.

You want to get a half of this value:

```
90 * (n-2) / n
4: 45
5: 54
6: 60
8: 67.5
```